# listen for an event fired in a sibling view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a view that contains two sub views, each with their own HTML template.

It works fine for what I have now. However, I now need an event to be fired from one subview to the other.

For example, when the user is in the Edit View, and they forget to click something(checkbox, radio button, or whatever), and they go back to the Display View, I want a warning to show up in that display view template(html) that warns them of the things they missed.

Is this possible?  To pass events around like this between sibling views?

Thanks!

Here's the basic code structure I have now:

return Backbone.View.extend({

```
        render: function(SubView) {
        SubView = SubView || DisplayView;
                this.view = new SubView({
                model: this.model
        });
        this.$el.html(this.view.render().$el);
        return this;
        }
 })

var DisplayView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    render: function() {
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    })

var EditView = Backbone.View.extend ({ 

    toggleDisplay: function () {
        this.checkAllItems();
    },

    checkAllItems: function() {
         if (this.$('.engineParts').val().length > 0) {
            this.render(DisplayView);
         } else {
            this.$('.awarning').css('display', 'block');   //warning class in DisplayView template.
            this.render(DisplayView);
         }
    }

})
```

Comment: What is the role of the first view..? `this.render(DisplayView);` i don't see a `render` method in `EditView `. Am I missing something..?

Comment: It just has a simple render method to display the html template.  I've added it in.

Comment: You have `this.render(...)` inside `EditView`. The `this` keyword should be pointing to `EditView` and it doesn't seem to have a `render` method...